# Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping when I include another class

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

Whenever I include the Dish class to a restaurant class, there is a `Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping` exception that occurs. When I do not include the dish class however, everything works fine. How can I include the dish class without this error occurring?

The Entity Model:

```
    public class Restaurant : IEqualityComparer<Restaurant>
    {
        public Restaurant()
        {

        }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public bool HasDelivery { get; set; }
        public int AdressId { get; set; }

       
        public virtual Adress Adress{ get; set; }
        public  List<Dish> Dishes { get; set; }

        public bool Equals(Restaurant x, Restaurant y)
        {
            if (x.Name == y.Name)  return true;
            else return false;
        }
      
                

    public int GetHashCode([DisallowNull] Restaurant obj)
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }
```

The View Model:

```
    public class RestaurantDataModel : IEqualityComparer<Entitties.Restaurant>
    {
        public RestaurantDataModel()
        {

        }
        
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public bool HasDelivery { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string Street { get; set; }
        public int HomeNumber { get; set; }




        public List<DishDataModel> Dishes { get; set; }

        public bool Equals(Entitties.Restaurant x, Entitties.Restaurant y)
        {
            if (x.Name == y.Name) return true;
            else return false;
        }

        public int GetHashCode([DisallowNull] Restaurant obj)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Create Map:

```
    public  class RestaurantMapper 
    {
        IMapper mapper;
        public RestaurantMapper()
        {
          mapper = new MapperConfiguration(config => config.CreateMap<Entitties.Restaurant, DataModels.RestaurantDataModel>()
                 .ForMember(x=>x.City,c=>c.MapFrom(s=>s.Adress.City))
                 .ForMember(x => x.HomeNumber, c => c.MapFrom(s => s.Adress.HomeNumber))
                 .ForMember(x => x.Street, c => c.MapFrom(s => s.Adress.Street))
                 .ForMember(x => x.Dishes, c => c.MapFrom(s => s.Dishes)))
                .CreateMapper();


            mapper = new MapperConfiguration(config => config.CreateMap<Entitties.Dish, DataModels.DishDataModel>()).CreateMapper();
            ;
        }
        public DataModels.RestaurantDataModel Map(Entitties.Restaurant restaurant)
        {
            
                return mapper.Map<DataModels.RestaurantDataModel>(restaurant);
            
          
          

        }
        public Entitties.Restaurant Map(DataModels.RestaurantDataModel restaurantDataModel)
        {
            return mapper.Map<Entitties.Restaurant>(restaurantDataModel);

        }
    }
MAP :

      [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult<IEnumerable<RestarantApplicationDataBase.Entitties.Restaurant>> getAllRestaurants()
        {
            
            RestaurantRepository.SaveChanges();
          
            var result = RestaurantRepository.GetAllRestaurants().FirstOrDefault();
            var g = mRestaurantMapper.Map(result);
           
            
            
            return Ok(g);
        }
```

The method where I include Dishes to the Restaurant:

```
     public IEnumerable<Entitties.Restaurant> GetAllRestaurants()
        {
            var allRestaurants = new List<Restaurant>();
            var restaurant = dbContext.Restaurants.Include(c=>c.Adress).Include(c=>c.Dishes).ToList();



            foreach (var item in restaurant)
            {
                
                allRestaurants.Add(item);
                
                     


            }
            return allRestaurants;


        }
```

Comment: you would need to create a Map between `DishDataModel` and `Dish`. At the moment, there is no mapping between the two types

Comment: I Added in Create Map : "mapper = new MapperConfiguration(config => config.CreateMap<Entitties.Dish, DataModels.DishDataModel>().ReverseMap()).CreateMapper();"

Comment: You are replacing the configuration in the second mapping. Instead you need to add it along with the original configuration

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the configurations in the second assignment of `mapper`. You would need both configurations.

```
var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
    cfg.CreateMap<Foo, Bar>();
    cfg.CreateMap<AnotherFoo, AnotherBar>();
});
```

In your example,

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(config => 
{
config.CreateMap<Entitties.Restaurant, DataModels.RestaurantDataModel>()
             .ForMember(x=>x.City,c=>c.MapFrom(s=>s.Adress.City))
             .ForMember(x => x.HomeNumber, c => c.MapFrom(s => s.Adress.HomeNumber))
             .ForMember(x => x.Street, c => c.MapFrom(s => s.Adress.Street))
             .ForMember(x => x.Dishes, c => c.MapFrom(s => s.Dishes));

config.CreateMap<Entitties.Dish, DataModels.DishDataModel>();
});

var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
```